# How to turn a 2D Array into a 1D array in Julia

Tags: julia

I have this 2D Array: `a = [ (1,2) (2,3) ; (3,4) (4,5)]` which I want to convert into:

```
(1, 2)
(2, 3)
(3, 4)
(4, 5)
#1D Array
```

How can I do this in Julia?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would also comment on other approaches.

First two traverse the `Matrix` columnwise not rowwise:

```
julia> a[:]
4-element Array{Tuple{Int64,Int64},1}:
 (1, 2)
 (3, 4)
 (2, 3)
 (4, 5)
```

which copies data and:

```
julia> vec(a)
4-element Array{Tuple{Int64,Int64},1}:
 (1, 2)
 (3, 4)
 (2, 3)
 (4, 5)
```

which shares the underlying data with `a`. Here is a consequence:

```
julia> b = vec(a)
4-element Array{Tuple{Int64,Int64},1}:
 (1, 2)
 (3, 4)
 (2, 3)
 (4, 5)

julia> b[1] = (100, 100)
(100, 100)

julia> b
4-element Array{Tuple{Int64,Int64},1}:
 (100, 100)
 (3, 4)
 (2, 3)
 (4, 5)

julia> a
2×2 Array{Tuple{Int64,Int64},2}:
 (100, 100)  (2, 3)
 (3, 4)      (4, 5)
```

You can use an explicit comprehension which allows you to do it both ways:

```
julia> [a[i,j] for j in axes(a, 2) for i in axes(a, 1)]
4-element Array{Tuple{Int64,Int64},1}:
 (1, 2)
 (3, 4)
 (2, 3)
 (4, 5)

julia> [a[i,j] for i in axes(a, 1) for j in axes(a, 2)]
4-element Array{Tuple{Int64,Int64},1}:
 (1, 2)
 (2, 3)
 (3, 4)
 (4, 5)
```

Finally you can use `vcat`, again both ways:

```
julia> reduce(vcat, eachrow(a))
4-element Array{Tuple{Int64,Int64},1}:
 (1, 2)
 (2, 3)
 (3, 4)
 (4, 5)

julia> reduce(vcat, eachcol(a))
4-element Array{Tuple{Int64,Int64},1}:
 (1, 2)
 (3, 4)
 (2, 3)
 (4, 5)
```

Answer (score 2):

Julia provides a simple interface for converting 2D Arrays into a single 1D array. It is important to note that there are other ways to approach converting a 2D array into a 1D array but those approaches may not give you the same order of elements in the 1D Array.

See the example below:

```
julia> a = [ (1,2) (2,3) ; (3,4) (4,5)]
2×2 Array{Tuple{Int64,Int64},2}:
 (1, 2)  (2, 3)
 (3, 4)  (4, 5)

julia> reshape(a, 4, 1)
4×1 Array{Tuple{Int64,Int64},2}:
 (1, 2)
 (3, 4)
 (2, 3)
 (4, 5)
# Note the order here may not be what you want. 

julia> b = [permutedims(a)...]
4-element Array{Tuple{Int64,Int64},1}:
 (1, 2)
 (2, 3)
 (3, 4)
 (4, 5)
```

[See the Julia docs to read more about `permutedims`.](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/arrays/#Base.permutedims)

[See the Julia docs to read more about `reshape`.](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/arrays/#Base.reshape)